# Implementing the .scrollto jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript / jQuery and trying to get the .scrollTo plugin to work. http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

I am looking to create a button with the ability to click it and scroll down to a specific div. Here is what I have so far and I am not sure if there is any other code I need to include or if anything else is causing it to not work.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#relative-selector').click(function() {
        $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo('#explanation', 800);
    });
</script>


<a id="relative-selector" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to jqeryscrollto reference demo

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

$.scrollTo( this.hash, 1500, { easing:'elasout' });

Try removing the `paneTarget.stop()` so that it looks like

```
$.scrollTo('#explanation', 800);
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I see your question in more detail now. Do you have the DIV with the ID #explanation on the page? You wouldn't need to take my original edit. Change it back to #explanation but make sure you have #explanation on your page reference. I don't see anything else initially.

Comment: Yes I have a div with the ID #explanation.

Comment: I edited my original answer. Try removing the paneTarget.stop() portion of your code.